# Why does the "skin" modifier not accurately produce 90°corners?

Tags: modifiers

My current design is comprised of a single path of vertices, defined by vertical and horizontal edges linked by 90° corners. Applying the skin modifier to this path of vertices creates perfect rectangular segments, but the corners display concave artifacts.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest using a combination of Screw + Solidify modifier (your base mesh must be flat for the best result) :

Screw : Along Z, 1 step *(If using Blender  < V2.83, the minimum steps is 2. Make sure the angle is 0°)*, Remove smooth shading

Solidify : Complex mode, offset 0

[image]

If you want to have the height centered around 0, simply add a displace with a driver :

[image]

Result :

[image]

Add custom properties if you don't want to deal with the modifier interface :

[image]

Comment: More parametric goodness from Gorgious : ) .. are you enjoying Houdini?

Comment: @RobinBetts Didn't have much time to use it !! But definitely having fun with the first few tutorials :)

Comment: Nice use of the *Screw* modifier, I'd have never though of that

Comment: It is also a nice way to create walls from .dxf in arch viz

Comment: This is a perfect solution to my question. Thank you so much for the detailed walkthrough.

Answer (score 4):

**If** your path is flat, then making it a poly-curve, then setting it to 2D and object-bevelling it in its *Geometry* panel with another, square, curve, will produce perfect mitres at the corners.

[image]