# How to get solid right angles with python?

Tags: python, bmesh

Using the script below I encounter the same non-orthogonal corners as already asked [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179816/why-does-the-skin-modifier-not-accurately-produce-90corners), **but** my bmesh is three dimensional, **not** flat.

[image: screenshot]

Is my current `skin` modifier approach even the best solution or is there another which doesn't even raise the corner problem at all?

```py
import bpy
vertices=[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1]]
edges=[[0,1],[1,2]]
faces = []

name = "my_bmesh"
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)

coll = bpy.data.collections.get("Collection")
coll.objects.link(obj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
mesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)

# Add skin modifier
mod_skin = obj.modifiers.new('Skin', 'SKIN')
# Add radius
dim = (0.3, 0.3)

for v in obj.data.skin_vertices[0].data:
    v.radius = dim
```

Comment: I think the skin modifier is not the way to go here, they tend to generate non-reliable results at intersections. Maybe a Geometry nodes approach would better suit you ? Try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260294/86891 + yay, that's my answer you linked ^^

Comment: @Gorgious That's the answer. Thank you